# Rotate the turret and muzzle of the tank

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, rotation, game-physics

It is necessary to rotate the turret and muzzle so that the sight is always directed to the center of the screen. I have a camera that can be rotated separately, and the turret and muzzle should follow it slowly, like in the world of tanks. 
I have this code. The tower does not keep up with the camera and stops where I took the camera.

```
public class Tower : MonoBehaviour
{
   public Transform Towr;
   public Transform Cannon;
   public float TowerSpeed;
   public float CannonSpeed;
   float TowerAngle;
   float CannonAngle;

   private void Update()
   {
      RotateTower();
      RotateCannon();
   }

   void RotateTower()
   {
      TowerAngle += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * TowerSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
      TowerAngle = Mathf.Clamp(TowerAngle, -90, 90);
      Towr.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(TowerAngle, Vector3.up);
   }

   void RotateCannon()
   {
      CannonAngle += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * CannonSpeed * -Time.deltaTime;
      CannonAngle = Mathf.Clamp(CannonAngle, -2, 2);
      Cannon.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(CannonAngle, Vector3.right);
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify the question a bit, I think we know what you're looking for but, it's not clear what the behavior is of the current code.

Comment: Method"RotateTower"rotates the tower along the "Y" axis with a limit of 90 degrees in both directions. The"RotateCannon"method raises or lowers the cannon at the point where it is attached to the turret. All this moves with the mouse. That is, when I turn the mouse outside the tower or cannon, and then sharply in the other direction, it immediately turns, but it needs to wait until I turn the mouse. I think this can be done by making the turret and cannon follow not the mouse, but the center of the screen. But I don't understand how to do it at all. Who played World of Tanks will understand me

Comment: Where is your camera rotation? Is it setting the speed for any of the tube/cannon or turret? If your camera can rotate outside of the extents that you can actually aim then I would look at the follow method. Because this code looks right.

Answer (score 0):

I already found a solution how to rotate the tower behind the camera along the "Y" axis

```
   public Transform cam;
   public float speed = 50f;

   private void FixedUpdate()
   {
      transform.localRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.localRotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, cam.eulerAngles.y , 0), speed * Time.deltaTime);
   }
```